# Web server/db online to communicate with android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android and i want to know if there is some server / web service online that o can use to update and communicate with my app?

example: I have the app "message" in 5 phones so I want to communicate with all of them, if the phone 1 send a message all device must receive notification.

There is something that I can use maybe free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options to accomplish this goal, and most provide some free level of support.

In general if you want to "push" notifications to android devices, you can either directly use or use some provider that uses [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

Using this approach directly means you need some web server to send request to, which will then forward a request to Google, which will then forward your "message" to the devices you want to reach.  There are many options for free hosting of (smallish) web services. [IBM's BlueMix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/home/) and [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) come to mind.  So if your are comfortable writing web apps, this might be a good choice.   I have used both (for Ruby on Rails backends to mobile apps) and found both very good, but am currently using Bluemix.

I believe [Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/home/) along with [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) also offer mobile data storage and easy access to Push notifications to both Android and iOS.  I am currently using Bluemix via Ruby on Rails and pushing messages directly to devices via [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and don't have much experience with those particular offerings.